# Why is my scoreTextNode not returning score?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

After my game ends, I added a PNG file with custom font and tried adding score in front of it, but when the game is over, the PNG file gets added and instead of putting the score in front of it, it prints out the details of the PNG file like this, 'ScoreText' (150 x 50 ) position:(465.4356789)....

All of this is happening in my didBeginContact method:

```
            let score = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ScoreText")
            score.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2.2, y: size.height / 1.9)
            self.addChild(score)


            let scoreTextNode = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Copperplate")
            scoreTextNode.text = "\(score)"
            scoreTextNode.fontSize = 12
            scoreTextNode.fontColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
            scoreTextNode.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 1.1, y: size.height / 1.9)
            addChild(scoreTextNode)
```

Comment: That is because you are making the text an `SKSpriteNode`... Where do you actually store the score?

Comment: You are referencing your `score` `SKSpriteNode` when you are setting up the `scoreTextNode.text = "\(score)"` instead of the variable which is holding your score.

Comment: Thanks guys. It is working now that vacawama mentioned that I was referring to the wrong thing. I changed my score SKSpriteNode name to scoreText and it worked. I really appreciate the help :)